# OOPHP Regex for White Spaces

Tags: php, regex

I am building a OOPHP web application, I am working on a regular expression that ONLY accepts lower/capital case letter along with white spaces. I have been trying to implement the white spaces but for some reason it not working, normally in JAVACC I do something like this:

```
(["a" - "z"])+ | (["A" - "Z"])+ | " " | "\t" | "\n" | "\r"
```

How can I rewrite the top expression in PHP? This is what I have so far (it works, but I don't know how to implement the white spaces in php).

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use `\s`?

Comment: @Popnoodles, I didn't know that at all, in JAVACC there is no such thing as \s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your character class to allow for whitespace. You can either add a space character `" "` if spaces are all you want to match, or use `\s` which matches whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\f`, and `" "`)

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/
```

Regular expression:

```
^               # the beginning of the string
[a-zA-Z\s]*     # any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
$               # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add that very space character to your existing regex as long as its the whitespace you want to match, and not the other form of spaces like a tab etc.

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/
         ^
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I rather use the \s as am not a too friendly with white spaces in code.